# Bootstrap Inline dropdown menus do not have correct width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two simple dropdown menus with Bootstrap v3. I want it so that they are displayed side by side with a width and utilizing the grid.

But it seems that the width stays the same. HEre is what I mean:

```css
.menuList > div.dropdownInline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="menuList">
<div class="dropdown dropdownInline">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" style="max-width:1200px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #dddddd;">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
          Warning!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          Danger!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">What an informatical message.</div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

<!-- SECOND DROPDOWN -->

<div class="dropdown dropdownInline">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="max-width:850px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #dddddd;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div></div>
<hr />
<h1>Without inline... </h1>

<div class="menuList">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" style="max-width:1200px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #dddddd;">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
          Warning!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          Danger!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">What an informatical message.</div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

<!-- SECOND DROPDOWN -->

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="max-width:850px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #dddddd;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div></div>
```

Do you see how without inline... the dropdown stretches fine into a nice width but ... with it.. (top menus)... it becomes squished? And one doesn't even show the blue panel.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just set width of menu

```
.dropdown-menu{
  width:400px;//or whatever you want
}
```

check this out
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0CjqVDVt37dMS4zSyOgQ?p=preview)

`.dropdowm-menu` is as small as it's content
so you can just fix it like above or set width of it's children element.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menuList > div.dropdownInline {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown button{ margin-top:5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="menuList">
<div class="dropdown dropdownInline">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" style="max-width:1200px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #dddddd;">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
          Warning!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          Danger!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">What an informatical message.</div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

<!-- SECOND DROPDOWN -->

<div class="dropdown dropdownInline">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="max-width:850px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #dddddd;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div></div>
<hr />
<h1>Without inline... </h1>

<div class="menuList">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" style="max-width:1200px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #dddddd;">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
          Warning!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
          Danger!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">What an informatical message.</div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

<!-- SECOND DROPDOWN -->

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" style="max-width:850px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #dddddd;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div></div>
```

Just add it

Comment: I do not care about the margin or height on the 2nd pair of dropdown menus. On the first one, the dropdown menus are not a fixed width.